# How to merge identical tables in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

There is probably a simple solution to this but I can't seem to figure it out.
I have 4 tables with identical columns which I want to merge together. I had to split them earlier due to the JOIN EACH limitations in Bigquery.

Example data table 1:

```
1|A
2|B
3|C
```

table 2:

```
4|D
5|E
6|F
```

merged table desired result:

```
1|A
2|B
3|C
4|D
5|E
6|F
```

Could somebody show me which query to use to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

In BigQuery Legacy SQL, a comma is a UNION ALL operation.

```
SELECT ... FROM table1, table2 WHERE ...
```

For standard SQL, you need to use UNION ALL operator explicitly